# Implement OpenID in Python

Tags: python, openid

How should I implement OpenID in Python using the OpenID API?

Answer (score 3):

For hassle free installation of openid use the [RPX](https://rpxnow.com/)
The installation is quite simple. visit the website for more details. You will be able to understand it very easily.

Comment: bro i have visited RPX.have you worked on openid related programming??

Comment: hello gaurav, i was busy in another module thts y i couldnt reply you.

i telling you the steps which i had taken...

1) downloaded the python-openid janrain lib in python language.
2) installed it 
3) now i import these lib in my programe
4) i have studied many articles, visited so many website which are using openid concept, still i have problem 


actually i'm using this concept for third party authentication.

1) enter openid_url and password at opening page
2) checking openid_url(exist?)
3) checking password corresponding openid_url

how should i do this steps in my app.